# why isn't the view expand to fill the remain space

Tags: android, attributes, autofill

I want to expand the webview1 view to fill the space remainning. make the button look like always on the bottom of Screen.
I assign a weight to individual children with the android:layout_weight attribute.
but It seems doesn't work. How can I do it ,can anybody tell me anything

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView style="@style/ScrollView" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1" >      <---here assign a weight

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webview1"
                    **style="@style/update_text" />**
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- h-line -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/line_end"
                    style="@style/form_h_line" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- buttons -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_ok"
                    style="@style/base_button"
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="OK"/>

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

The reason is  , because it works in Framelayout, so the webview1 can't expand automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fill_parent`/`match_parent` does not work in a `ScrollView` for obvious reasons - if it did, the `ScrollView` would be useless.

Your `ScrollView` should have `fillViewPort` attribute set to `true`. This makes the `ScrollView`'s child expand to height of the `ScrollView` if needed. If the child is larger than the screen, the attribute has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Add `weightSum="" property to your LinearLayout`

so use following and manage it as you want `with wiegtSum and layout_weight` also Use LinearLayout instead of `<Space>` tag

```
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_ok"
                style="@style/base_button"
                android:layout_width="12dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="OK"/>
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, I mean I want to expand the WebView id/webview1 to the remain space. now before the webview is loaded by URL content, the button is showed on the top of the screen. so I want to expand the webview even if there is no content in webview